# XCUITest how to locate tabs position with reference to one another

Tags: xcuitest

There are 4 tabs in my application tabors.

- tabA
- tabB
- tabC
- tabD

I have to validate that they are in the same position going from left to right 
tabA tabB tabC tabD

For example a failure would look like this
tabB tabC tabA tabD

Is there a way to test this using XCUITest. I looked up in Xcode documentation but it does not have what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use `element(boundBy: Int)` in combination with strings on your tabs - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementquery/1500842-element

I am assuming, that your tabs contain some text (lets say the text on them is *tabA, tabB, tabC, tabD*), so the best solution would be checking ***text on the tab*** and ***index of the tab***. 
By checking text, you know, that the element is the right tab (tabA, tabB...) and by checking element index, you know, that it it on the right position.

After this, its simple - find your way to tabbar buttons (its usually: f.e. `XCUIApplication.tabBars.buttons["tabA"]`). Than check their string and position like this:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let tabA = XCUIApplication.tabBars.buttons["tabA"].element(boundBy: 0)//tabA is on the first position
let tabB = XCUIApplication.tabBars.buttons["tabB"].element(boundBy: 1)//tabB is on the second position etc...
let tabC = XCUIApplication.tabBars.buttons["tabC"].element(boundBy: 2)
let tabD = XCUIApplication.tabBars.buttons["tabD"].element(boundBy: 3)

XCTAssertTrue(tabA.exists) 
XCTAssertTrue(tabB.exists) 
XCTAssertTrue(tabC.exists) 
XCTAssertTrue(tabD.exists)
```

Edit: instead of strings, I would suggest using `accessibilityIdentifier` - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilityidentification#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UIAccessibilityIdentification/accessibilityIdentifier